# EF Model with collection and navigation to a particular element

Tags: entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

How to configure a EF6 migration with a model class having?

- A collection o items
- A navigation property to one particular item

```cs
public class MyModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // My collection of elements
    public virtual ICollection<MyCollectionElement> MyCollection { get; set; }

    // Optional navigation to a particular element from the collection
    [ForeignKey("CurrentElement")]
    public int? CurrentElementId { get; set; }

    public virtual MyCollectionElement CurrentElement { get; set; }
}

public class MyCollectionElement
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Required navigation to MyClass
    [ForeignKey("MyModel")]
    public int MyModelID { get; set; }

    public virtual MyModel Model { get; set; }
}
```

Configuration

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<MyModel>()
    .HasMany(x => x.MyCollection)
    .WithRequired(x => x.Model)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.MyModelID)
    .WillCascadadeOnDelete(false);
```

Throws several errors on `Update-Database`, like

*Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations.*

I would like a solution which doesn't involve a `boolean IsCurrent` in *MyCollectionElement* to make another query later and find which element is the current; instead, I would like to store the current element's id with my model, like exposed.

Also, I don't mind making `int CurrentElementId` non nullable (**required**) if it's easier.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This chicken-and-egg problem always looms when there are circular relationships. The error...

> Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations.

...is not thrown when the database is created. The database can be created just fine. It occurs when you try to insert a `MyModel` record and a `MyCollectionElement` referring to one another in the same unit of work. In the `Seed` method you probably have something like

```
var element = new MyCollectionElement();
var model = new MyModel();
model.MyCollection.Add(element);
model.CurrentElement = element;
```

The statement `model.MyCollection.Add(element);` requires `model` to be inserted first, so `element` can refer to it in its foreign key. But `model.CurrentElement = element;` requires `element` to be inserted first.

You can only avoid this situation by calling `SaveChanges` twice, and wrapping everything in a `TransactionScope` if you want the assignments to be transactional:

```
using(var ts = new TransactionScope())
{    
    using(var db = new MyContext()
    {
        var element = new MyCollectionElement();
        var model = new MyModel();
        model.MyCollection.Add(element);
        db.MyModels.Add(model);
        db.SaveChanges();

        model.CurrentElement = element;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    ts.Complete();
}
```

This also means that `int CurrentElementId` should remain nullable.